# XML Marshalling generates XML without Root

Tags: xml, go, encoding, marshalling, sqlx

I am working on a rest api in golang and was able to marshal data to xml and json. The struct i have has multiple records but xml marshalling does not add a root for these records. The XML is therefore not valid.

I saw some questions that were solved by setting XMLName but i think that will only change my customer type to something else.

What i still might try is to add  around the xml marshalled byte and concatinate. But I am not sure if that is how i have to do it.

**EDIT: Apparently XML is marshalled correctly since I am marshalling a struct with multiple objects inside. Marshalling then creates separate XML documents per object. Question then is what the rest clients can work with to consume data or is it bad practice to send multiple xml documents in a rest responce? Browsers couldn't display the resulting xml.**

**To return a single XML Document I would have to put the list in a struct, which then can be marshalled. I am not sure how I can initialise the struct with sqlx in such a way.**

**Adding following code does not work:**

```
type custs struct {
    List []Customer `xml:"Customer"`
}

custs customers.[]Customer =  []Customer{}
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    json "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type Customer struct {
    CustomerID int            `db:"CustomerId"`
    FirstName  string         `db:"FirstName"`
    LastName   string         `db:"LastName"`
    Company    sql.NullString `db:"Company"`
}

func tstSQLite(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    contentType := r.Header.Get("Content-type")

    Customers := []Customer{}

    var err error

    fmt.Print("executing query")
    err = chinookdb.Select(&Customers, "SELECT CustomerId, FirstName,LastName, Company FROM customers")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, g := range Customers {
        fmt.Println("FirstName:", g.FirstName, "LastName:", g.LastName)
    }

    var data []byte

    if contentType == "application/xml" {
        data, err = xml.Marshal(Customers)
    }

    if contentType == "application/json" || contentType != "application/xml" {
        data, err = json.Marshal(Customers)
    }


    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(data)
}
```

What i get is following xml:

```
   <Customer>
      <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
      <FirstName>Luís</FirstName>
      <LastName>Gonçalves</LastName>
      <Company>
         <String>Embraer - Empresa Brasileira de Aeronáutica S.A.</String>
         <Valid>true</Valid>
      </Company>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
      <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
      <FirstName>Leonie</FirstName>
      <LastName>Köhler</LastName>
      <Company>
         <String />
         <Valid>false</Valid>
      </Company>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
      <CustomerID>3</CustomerID>
      <FirstName>François</FirstName>
      <LastName>Tremblay</LastName>
      <Company>
         <String />
         <Valid>false</Valid>
      </Company>
   </Customer>
```

but i think it should be like this:

```
<Customers>
   <Customer>
      <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
      <FirstName>Luís</FirstName>
      <LastName>Gonçalves</LastName>
      <Company>
         <String>Embraer - Empresa Brasileira de Aeronáutica S.A.</String>
         <Valid>true</Valid>
      </Company>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
      <CustomerID>2</CustomerID>
      <FirstName>Leonie</FirstName>
      <LastName>Köhler</LastName>
      <Company>
         <String />
         <Valid>false</Valid>
      </Company>
   </Customer>
   <Customer>
      <CustomerID>3</CustomerID>
      <FirstName>François</FirstName>
      <LastName>Tremblay</LastName>
      <Company>
         <String />
         <Valid>false</Valid>
      </Company>
   </Customer>
</Customers>
```

The marshalled json looks correct since the customers are in brackets:

```
[
   {
      "CustomerID":1,
      "FirstName":"Luís",
      "LastName":"Gonçalves",
      "Company":{
         "String":"Embraer - Empresa Brasileira de Aeronáutica S.A.",
         "Valid":true
      }
   },
   {
      "CustomerID":2,
      "FirstName":"Leonie",
      "LastName":"Köhler",
      "Company":{
         "String":"",
         "Valid":false
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a struct holding the slice?

Comment: ... https://play.golang.org/p/Ggo2_B191oF

Comment: The XML is also correct, regardless of wether this is what you wanted. You were writing numerous XML documents with the root element `Customer` to the same file.

Comment: So i just got confused. Question then is what the rest clients can work with to consume data or is it bad practice to send multiple xml documents in a rest responce? Browsers couldn't display the resulting xml.

Comment: Interesting. As per convention, I would always expect a single entity as a response. As for your JSON, that would be fulfilled, as a single entity of type list is returned, whereas your XML would be multiple independent documents. I personally would adhere to the single response entity, simply because it is not wrong in both cases. Especially for XML, assuming that there is some sort of validity check on the other end (we always validate XML responses and requests against XSDs) I would prefer to have to run it a single time instead of multiple times. Questions regarding atomicity raise, too.

Comment: @WMettler Please [add your elaboration to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55933508/edit) - it makes it much more interesting and relevant.

Comment: @mkopriva I tried putting it in a separate struct, but i don't know how i can do that using sqlx. What i have so far does not compile

Comment: @WMettler https://play.golang.org/p/Hel7OQ9zi80 no need to force the xml specific solution onto sqlx or json.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to wrap this customer collection inside another struct as

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type Customer struct {
        XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"Customer"`
        CustomerID int            `db:"CustomerId"`
        FirstName  string         `db:"FirstName"`
        LastName   string         `db:"LastName"`
        Company    string `db:"Company"`
    }

    type Customers struct {
        List []Customer
    }

    csts := []Customer{
        Customer{CustomerID: 1, FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe", Company: "Demo Company"},
        Customer{CustomerID: 2, FirstName: "John2", LastName: "Doe2", Company: "Demo Company2"},
    }


    res := Customers {
        List: csts,
    }

    output, err := xml.MarshalIndent(res, "  ", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v\n", err)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(output)
}
```

Default it could take the name of construct. You can also customized the name using xml.Name type.

Comment: Here is the official documentation you can follow. https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal